# What does the phrase "tool manufacture and food for your livestock" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "tool manufacture and food for your livestock" in the following sentence (not available online) from the description of the game "Family Island":

> Soon you will find yourself industrialising your proto-settlement,
> building machines for weaving, **tool manufacture and food for your
> livestock**.

I am wondering if the sentence above is incomplete.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's easier to understand with an Oxford comma: Soon you will find yourself industrialising your proto-settlement, building machines for weaving, tool manufacture, and food for your livestock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to say, in effect, "building machines for" three things: weaving, tool manufacture and food for your livestock.
What sort of machine is "for food for your livestock"?
It doesn't seem quite right.